# git merge with remote branch: already up to date

Tags: git, merge, fetch

I am on `master` branch in local and I've added a remote repository, so my `git branch -a` command shows like this:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev
```

Now something has been updated in remote branch `dev`, so I'd like to fetch these changes and merge them with my local `master` branch, so I run:

```
git fetch origin dev
git merge origin/dev
```

However it shows:

```
[myname@website]git fetch origin dev
From  https://github.com/Aprilbunny/myTest
 * branch            dev     -> FETCH_HEAD
[myname@website]$ git merge origin/dev
Already up-to-date.
```

So strange, so I tested with `git diff master origin/dev`, and it seems that I didn't get the last changes in remote branch `dev`.
I tried with `rebase` but got the same error, any idea would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
`git fetch --all
git checkout master
git merge origin/dev`
```

The issue is with your fetch command. You could have used too `git fetch origin dev:dev` to tell git you want to fetch the remote branch dev into the current branch dev